# Sql Query for number of available and total books

Tags: sql, sqlite

> I need a query which will  return list of book from book table
>
> but it will  show total number of books and books available too ..

And for number of books it will count number of books with simular ISBN n amount count which will count number of books with simular ISBN with status available

Table structure

```
Bookid booktitle author ISBN edition publisher price supplier volume language status

status contains available,issued
```

I want result as

```
BookTitle Author Publisher Location Total available
```

Please also explain the query because I need to implement it on many tables

Queries i tried this far

```
select *,count(1) as Quantity from Book group  by Book.BookTitle
```

It successfully gives me book list with total quantity

and

```
select *,count(1) as Quantity from Book where status='Available' group  by Book.BookTitle
```

It Successfully gives me list of books with how many are available.

but i need combination of both total and available ..

Comment: how result should look like?

Comment: BookTitle Author Publisher Location Total available

Comment: so, total will be duplicate in each row?

Comment: No . Total wont be duplicate in each row , it will display total if particular book its like , a library has 10 book of "Programming in c' , 5 are issued so total books are 10 and available are 5

Comment: give sample data and desired result

Comment: BookTitle   Author  Publisher  Total  Available<code>
Prog in c   Yashwant  abc        10      5 
Prog in c++   tttttt  abc        10      2</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brevi:

```
select isbn, booktitle, sum(case when status='available' then 1 else 0 end) as avail, count(*) as total
from Book
group by isbn, booktitle
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80a41/5

i definitely suggest you to read about 3rd normal form

Comment: [11:56:41] Error while executing SQL query: no such function: if

Answer (score 0):

You must group by all items in the SELECT query. You can either count(*) or sum(1). Here is how I would do:

```
SELECT BookId, Name, Available, count(*) as Quantity
FROM Book GROUP BY Bookid,Name,Available
```

Comment: Available has to be counted as well , please read the question properly .. Quantity means count all books regardless of status and Available means count of books with status available

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.* from (select BookTitle,Author,Publisher,Location,count(BookTitle) as Total, Status, Count(Status) as StatusQuantity from Book group by BookTitle,Author,Publisher,Location,Status)d where d.Status='Available'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
     BookTitle,
     Author,
     Publisher,
     Location, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN status='available' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Available,
     COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM Book
GROUP BY BookTitle,Author,Publisher,Location
```

Comment: This code returns correct number of available books but in total it gives 0 for every row

Comment: it is still not working, however got the accurate answer i needed from Lashane

Answer (score 0):

Are you have any key constraints??
you must split the table..
Using the **bookid or ISBN** as a **primary key**,store the status in a separate table..
it will be easy for further process otherwise the records should be redundant..